# number of connected sets

Tags: graph-theory

How many connected sets are there in the following array?

1 0 0 1

0 0 1 0

0 0 1 0

1 0 0 1

"Connected set" can be defined as group of cell(s) which has 1 mentioned on it and has at least one other cell in that set with which they share the neighbor relationship. A cell with 1 in it and no surrounding neighbor having 1 in it can be considered as a set with one cell in it. Neighbors can be defined as all the cells adjacent to the given cell in 8 possible directions ( i.e N , W , E , S , NE , NW , SE , SW direction ). A cell is not a neighbor of itself.

Actually i am stuck on this and not able to understand what the definition of connected set in this question means

Comment: do you need an answer for this particular case, or an algorithm for calculating the number of connected sets in any given array?

Comment: if you ans how to calcultae  this particular case then it would be enough

Comment: I think the answer to the above case is 3, but I'm not sure if this question is relevant to stackoverflow.

Comment: It looks like a connected set is any group of '1' cells that are adjacent to each other in the directions mentioned. A cell cannot be a neighbor of itself so the 1 in the upper left-hand corner does not and cannot belong to a set.

Comment: In my opinion connected cells count is 5, but do you looking for algorithm?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri i am not able to figure out whats the definition of connected sets in this question.



can you tell it in simple words.

Comment: Did you understand definition of adjacent cells?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri       yes..can you tell how the answer to this case is 3
http://pastebin.com/1XCnCHgp

Comment: I think answer to that case is 9 not 3, may be you missed something (or I missed), by current definition I can't see how it's 3.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri    sorry my mistake...its 9 can you tell how..

Comment: Assume it's a graph, 1's are nodes in the graph, and adjacent 1's are connected with an edge, now draw related graph yourself and see is there 9 connected components?

Comment: The pastebin one http://pastebin.com/1XCnCHgp is 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an image highlighting the sets:

[image: sets]

The rules apply as follows (as far as I understand):

- Cell must contain a 1 to be part of a set
- If a neighboring(up, down and diagonal) cell also contains a 1, it is part of the same set.
- A cell with 1 in it and no surrounding neighbor having 1 in it can be considered as a set with one cell in it

The third point I'm not so sure on, because the OP says "'Connected set' can be defined as group of cell(s) which has 1 mentioned on it and has at **least one other cell** in that set", but then also says "A cell with 1 in it and **no surrounding neighbor** having 1 in it can be considered as a set with one cell in it", so  it's very ambiguous.

If it's the case that single-cells are not sets, and the count is instead 1 and 5 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

one approach to solve the problem is use flood fill algorithm

now check for 1 and make it 0 and now check in all directions and if they contains 1 then also make them 0 (nothing but make a recursive call in all directions)

after the entire array checking is completed how many times does we faced 1 is the answer

for example let us take

1 0 0 1

1 0 0 1

1 0 0 1

1 0 1 0

now element at 00 is 1 now make it 0 and now check for in all directions now we are having 1 at 10 position hence make it zero and again check we will get 20 and 30 positions hence make a count as 1

now move to 03 make it 0 and now check for 1 hence cell containing 1 is 13 make it zero and now move to 23 and finally to 32 and increment counter hence it is 2

and now check for each and every cell since no other cells are containing 1 hence total connected sets are 2